# What is the best way to scrape the basketball player's team name?

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I can successfully scrape multiple columns, however, I haven't been able to grab the team name of the respective player. Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_advanced.html"

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)


for idx, bball_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
    names = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    mp = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="mp"]/text()')[0]
    per = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="per"]/text()')[0]
    ws = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="ws"]/text()')[0]
    bpm = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="bpm"]/text()')[0]
    vorp = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="vorp"]/text()')[0]
    print(names, per, ws, bpm, vorp)
```

Everything works up to this point. I would like to add the category of the team name, though. I am looking for the abbreviated team name (for example, OKC for Oklahoma City).

The following code ran into an error:

```
team = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]/a')[0].text
    print(team)
```

The code starts printing all of the team names then runs into an error.

Here is the error:

```
team = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]/a')[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Just to reiterate what I am looking for...
I am to trying to add the abbreviated team name next to the respective player.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I want to thank the community in advance for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script threw that error only when it didn't find that value it looked for. What you can do is catch the error and handle it in the right way. Try the below script:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_advanced.html"

content = requests.get(url).text
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)

for row in tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]'):
    names = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    mp = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="mp"]/text()')[0]
    per = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="per"]/text()')[0]
    ws = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="ws"]/text()')[0]
    bpm = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="bpm"]/text()')[0]
    vorp = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="vorp"]/text()')[0]
    try:
        team = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]/a')[0].text
    except IndexError: team = "N/A"
    print(names, per, ws, bpm, vorp, team)
```

Outputt you may get like:

```
Alex Abrines 9.0 2.2 -2.2 -0.1 OKC
Quincy Acy 8.2 1.0 -2.2 -0.1 BRK
Steven Adams 20.6 9.7 3.3 3.3 OKC
Bam Adebayo 15.7 4.2 0.2 0.8 MIA
```

Comment: `except IndexError: team = bball_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]/text()')[0]` ?

Comment: Yeah, that should be added as well. However, this can also be fixed like `except IndexError: team = "TOT"` because the only name not having any hyperlink is this one.

Comment: Amazing! @SIM... I just learned something new today thanks to you. Thank you sir =)

Comment: Thanks @G_M! I am thankful for your help. I will research this further to get a better understanding.